# How to get file path in node js selected in the input type file

Tags: html, node.js, file, file-io

I am new to the node js. I have and html form which is having file input like -

```
  <form action="importlist_action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select File: 
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" tabindex="1" />
  </form>
```

Now, I have redirected this post request to the following method of controller.

```
 exports.doImport = function(req, res) {
     console.log('Post values: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
     console.log("File path : " +  req.body.file);
 }
```

The result I am getting here is -

```
  Post values: {}
  File path : undefined
```

I want the path of the file which is selected on the form above in the controller. can some one please correct me what I am doing wrong here?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Most browsers will use `fakepath` for security reasons, so I don't think you'll get the actual path on the users computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Express 3.x and the bodyParser() middleware, then you should look under `req.files` for files.

If you're using Express 4.x, then you have to use a separate module to read a multipart request. Examples of such modules are: [busboy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/busboy)(/[connect-busboy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-busboy)/[multer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multer)/[reformed](https://www.npmjs.org/package/reformed)) and [formidable](https://www.npmjs.org/package/formidable).

As @adeneo mentioned, not all browsers provide the actual file *path*, but most will at least supply a filename. Both Busboy and Formidable make the filename available to you.

Comment: I am using Express 3.x, so it worked for me to use bodyParser().

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful that node.js does not upload files in a folder by default like PHP would.

What you are probably looking for is a middleware to do this for you:

http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/bodyParser.html